# 12 base units instead of 10

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Why do we use 10 as a whole unit when it can't be evenly divided by 3 or 6 without resulting in an infinite decimal I.e 3.3333etc.

If units of 12 were used I.e  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ? # 10. 3.3333 would become 3.4 (10/3=3.4)

In math, I'm told, if you have an infinite, something is wrong with the equation

So using a base of ten must be an incorrect way to measure

My apologies for the crudeness of this inquiry, I just typed it out on an iPod at a coffee shop real quick, little consideration for how articulate it comes out

Comment: Hexadactyly is rare.

Comment: The Mayans used $60.$ look what happened to them.

Comment: I am offended at the notion that there is something wrong with infinity :-)

Comment: The Sumerians and Babylonians used sexigecimal (base 60), and for this reason, hours have 60 minutes, minutes have 60 seconds, and circles have 360 degrees.

Comment: for any base you choose, some fractions will have infinite decimal expansions

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Mayans used a strange *almost* place-value system based on the number $20$.  I write "almost" because they represented numbers as $a_0 + a_1 \cdot 18 + a_2 \cdot 20^2 + a_3 \cdot 20^3 + \cdots$.  The surprising $18$ was to make the decimal number $360$ (a good approximation of the number of days in a year) look particularly nice in their number system:  $100$.

Comment: @Will: No, the Maya used $20$ (except in calendrical computation, for which they modified it to make the equivalent of $100$ equal to $360$ instead of $400$. You are perhaps thinking of the Babylonians.

Comment: Why don't we all just use continued fractions? I bet if everyone had to perform calculations on continued fractions to buy groceries the world would have been a whole lot smarter.

Comment: You wouldn't solve the problem of $1/7$. When in math you find something infinite, you don't worry and go on.

Comment: @David Thomas I think Thomas Jefferson or Benjamin Franklin (I forgot which) might have advocated base 12.

Comment: @StefanSmith The Dozenal Society of Great Britain and The Dozenal Society of America have a fair number of members advocating for base 12 in the Anglosphere today.

Answer (score 4):

Most things that are meaningful in mathematics are completely independent of representation - it's important that the notation doesn't affect the result. The fact that we don't have $12$ units is just a convention, mostly based on the fact that we have $10$ fingers.

Besides, base $12$ doesn't allow division by $5$ without an infinitely repeating expansion, so it doesn't really address your objection that some numbers have expansions that don't terminate.

In fact, almost every real number has a non-terminating expansion regardless of whether you're using a system based on $10$ units or $12$.

Comment: I was having trouble dividing by 5 using 12 units of measurement in my head, so that does make sense, what would the repetitive decimal be if 12 were divided by 5 where 0.6 represents 1/2 of 1.0?

Comment: Also, if every number used results in a non- terminating expansion, doesn't this mean there is something fundamentally wrong with math itself, almost comparable to relativity vs quantum mechanics, only string theory and extra dimensions were concieved to balance that out a little.

Comment: There are many human civilizations that didn't use base 10.  I don't think the people in those civilizations had extra or missing fingers to base their math system.